# Unexplainable error when using a stored procedure with HSQLDB

Tags: java, spring-boot, hsqldb

I want to use a simple stored procedure in my testclass, using an HSQLDB embedded database, with spring-boot data.

The stored procedure I want to use is defined in my schema.sql file, under 'test/resources' (tables are properly initialized):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE newPet(IN PETNAME varchar(50), IN AGE int, IN BREED varchar(50))
modifies sql
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO Pets(PETNAME, AGE, BREED);
END
```

Yet when I run this code using a callable statement in IntellijUltimate, the following error-message pops up:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #3 of URL [file:/C:/dev/codingdojo/jdbc/target/test-classes/schema.sql]: CREATE PROCEDURE newPet(IN PETNAME varchar(50), IN AGE int, IN BREED varchar(50)) modifies sql BEGIN ATOMIC INSERT INTO Pets(PETNAME, AGE, BREED); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE PROCEDURE[*] NEWPET(IN PETNAME VARCHAR(50), IN AGE INT, IN BREED VARCHAR(50)) MODIFIES SQL BEGIN ATOMIC INSERT INTO PETS(PETNAME, AGE, BREED)"; expected "OR, FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, SYNONYM, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX"; SQL statement:
CREATE PROCEDURE newPet(IN PETNAME varchar(50), IN AGE int, IN BREED varchar(50)) modifies sql BEGIN ATOMIC INSERT INTO Pets(PETNAME, AGE, BREED) [42001-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applySchemaScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 103 more
```

I cannot seem to find the cause for this - the part

```
expected "OR, FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, SYNONYM, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX"; SQL statement:
```

Does not make any sense to me. Could someone help?

Cheers!

Comment: Change your configuration to use HSQLDB instead of H2. On Maven Look for `<groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId> <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId> <version>2.6.1</version>`

Comment: Also change the INSERT statement to `INSERT INTO Pets VALUES (PETNAME, AGE, BREED);`